# Backbone JS and Polymer compatibility

Tags: backbone.js, polymer

Is there any limitation in having both Polymer and Backbone working alongside on a project?

I can't think of anything specific, but I thought I would ask before rushing in. Someone might work with both already and found some incompatibilities of some kind.

Any feedback and sharing of experience is most welcome.

Comment: There's no practical limitation since Backbone's View leaves the implementation up to you. You could use Polymer to make each of your views a custom element and use Backbone's Router and Model to manage data flow and state. I have used the Router to drive Polymer's `core-pages` component without any problems.

Comment: That's exaclty the kind of feedback I was looking for. Many thanks

Answer (score -2):

There's no practical limitation since Backbone's View leaves the implementation up to you. You could use Polymer to make each of your views a custom element and use Backbone's Router and Model to manage data flow and state. I have used the Router to drive Polymer's core-pages component without any problems. (From the comment of ssorallen).